# Select only some data by default in multi data series c3 charts

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

I have a very complicated multi-data chart as you can see in this picture:
[image]

As you can see, the C3 chart enables all data series by default and shows them in the chart together.

Now I want to know if there is a way I can select one or two data series to be shown as default (I mean when the page is loaded, one or two data series are enabled instead of all data in the chart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Let this be our example data:

```
data: {
   columns: [
     ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
     ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300],
     ['data3', 200, 150, 25, 250, 100],
   ],
 },
```

If you want to hide e.g. 'data2', use the following:

```
data: {
    hide: ['data2']
}
```

This will hide 'data2' series in the chart, but will still show all data series in the legend. If you also want to hide it from the legend, use:

```
legend: {
    hide: ['data2']
}
```

I have created a fiddle with two examples for you. The first one only hides the data in the chart, but still shows it in the legend. The second one hides it in both the chart and the legend: http://jsfiddle.net/hbge96xd/3/

Comment: tnx it was really helpful, just one more quick question: is there a way to make buttons works like checkboxes? I mean for example I enable 2 button by default and hide the others and set a value to make sure there are always 2 charts on the screen and if user select other chart, one of the charts go hides automaticly

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. Would you mind opening a new question along with a working example like JSFiddle?